# Sorting data on x-axis taking one variable as reference

Tags: r, sorting, ggplot2

Hello I think that this must be something stupid, but I am stuck..

I have 5 participants and two task

```
participant<-1:5
scoreA<- c(20, 18, 19, 15,16)
scoreB<- c(4, 2, 6, 1,3)
```

I create a data frame and I sort it using the variable scoreA as reference

```
total<- data.frame(scoreA, scoreB, participant)
total <- total[order(total[,1]),]
```

Because I want to create a graph line using ggplot I melt the data and try to do the graph:

```
totalM <- melt(total, id="participant", measured= c("scoreA", scoreB))
ggplot(totalM, aes(participant, value, shape= variable, linetype=variable))+geom_point(size=5)+geom_line(size=1)
```

I don't understand the reason why I don't see in the graph the data sorted using the variable scoreA as reference. Any idea? How can I do this?

Comment: I get a nice looking plot.  Do you want the graphs to both be up and to the right?  In that case you'd want to add `total$participant <- factor(total$participant)` to make it categorical, and you'd want to not have a line plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you want something like this?

[image]

```
# Convert participant to a factor, with order given by the scoreA variable
# from your "total" data frame
totalM$participant <- factor(totalM$participant,
                             levels=arrange(total, scoreA)$participant)

# Plot!
ggplot(totalM, aes(participant, value, shape= variable, linetype=variable)) +
  geom_point(size=5)+
  geom_line(aes(x=as.numeric(participant)), size=1)
# Note the last geom, I modified the aes
```

Basically, I make the `participant` variable a factor, ordered by `scoreA`. Then `ggplot` will plot the `participant` variable in the given factor order. One little adjustment I had to make to force `ggplot` to plot the lines is to grab the numeric value of the factor for the `participant` variable for `geom_line`.

This is the first thing that came to mind. Maybe there is a better way to do this?

Comment: That works perfectly. Thanks ialm. To be hones I thought it would be simpler. But, definitely It makes the job.

Comment: @ajestudillo. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it was what you were looking for.

Comment: @ajestudillo It is a little cumbersome at first, but it makes sense. Your `participant` variable is interpreted as a numeric quantity, so `ggplot` naturally uses a continuous x scale, hence the original ordering. The `participant` number is really a categorical variable, as it represents a person (I assume), and by default it orders it alphabetically. You just set the order manually, and voila.

Comment: NB:  Need the `plyr` package to use `arrange`